# NHibernate QueryOver with ManytoMany

Tags: nhibernate, queryover

I'm in the process of learning QueryOver, but I can't for my life figure out how to do simple many to many queries.

I've written the following:

```
            var result = Session.CreateCriteria(typeof (Product))
                .CreateAlias("Categories", "categories")
                .Add(Property.ForName("categories.Id").Eq(categoryId))
                .List<Product>();
```

This achieves the desired result. Basically I have

Product > ProductCategory < Category

ProductCategory just has ProductId / CategoryId, and I'm trying to select all the products in a specific category.

I have no idea where to start with trying to do this with queryover.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I ended up resolving this after a lot of perseverance.

```
            var result = Session.QueryOver<Product>()
                            .Right.JoinQueryOver<Category>(x => x.Categories)
                            .Where(c => c.Id == categoryId)
                            .List();
```

What a mission :)