# EF query to fluent nhibernate query

Tags: asp.net, nhibernate, fluent

I have EF Query:

```
IEnumerable<Account> accounts 
         = (
           from a in dc.Accounts
            join m in dc.GroupMembers on a.AccountID equals m.AccountID
            where m.GroupID == GroupID && m.IsApproved
            select a)
           .Skip((_configuration.NumberOfRecordsInPage * (PageNumber - 1)))
           .Take(_configuration.NumberOfRecordsInPage);
```

How to write it in fluent nhibernate query with `Session.CreateCriteria<>`?
(My problem is with Join)

Comment: There is no such thing as a "fluent nhibernate" query. Fluent NHibernate is an API to express the mapping definitions. When querying, regular NHibernate is used.

Comment: What prevents you from using the same LINQ query with NHibernate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a good answer by phill here -  [NHibernate QueryOver with ManytoMany](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3900779/nhibernate-queryover-with-manytomany/3905799#3905799)     which has an example of join with QueryOver

```
var result = Session.QueryOver<Product>()
                        .Right.JoinQueryOver<Category>(x => x.Categories)
                        .Where(c => c.Id == categoryId)
                        .List();
```

He also describes how to use linq with query over:

```
var users = from u in session.Query<Users>()
        where u.UserName == "Abcd"
        && u.Password == "123456"
        select u;
```

So applying the above examples to your query somethign like this might work:

```
(from a in session.Query<Account>()
                                     join m in session.Query<GroupMember>() on a.AccountID equals m.AccountID
                                     where m.GroupID == GroupID && m.IsApproved
                                     select a).Skip((_configuration.NumberOfRecordsInPage * (PageNumber - 1)))
                                     .Take(_configuration.NumberOfRecordsInPage);
```

However, to help better understand the issue you are having, could you post what you have attemtpted?